# removing hover selection in DT package with shinny

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I have small data that I am trying to display in shinny app with some custom user friendly features like download option feature, view small/all data and etc. my question is how to remove the hover effect because i am using color to highlight some values and when I select rows the hover kind of removes the coloring. can anyone help me how to remove the hover selection. below is the reproducible code that I am running... thanks in advance. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/whdo7.png). note the code does not contain the color portion

```
   library(DT)
library(tidyverse)
library(formattable)
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinythemes)
library(shinyWidgets)


table_options <- function() {
  list(
    dom = 'Bfrtip',
    #Bfrtip
    # pageLength = 10,
    buttons = list(
      c('copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'),
      list(
        extend = "collection",
        text = 'Show All',
        action = DT::JS(
          "function ( e, dt, node, config ) {
          dt.page.len(-1);
          dt.ajax.reload();}"
        )
        ),
      list(
        extend = "collection",
        text = 'Show Less',
        action = DT::JS(
          "function ( e, dt, node, config ) {
          dt.page.len(10);
          dt.ajax.reload();}"
        )
        )
        ),
    
    deferRender = TRUE,
    
    lengthMenu = list(c(-1,10,20), c('All', '10', '20')),
    searching = TRUE,
    #editable = TRUE,
    scroller = TRUE,
    lengthChange = FALSE
    ,
    initComplete = JS(
      "function(settings, json) {",
      "$(this.api().table().header()).css({'background-color': '#517fb9', 'color': '#fff'});",
      "}"
    )
      )
}


ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel( h1("Iris data view", align = 'center'),
              windowTitle = "Iris data "),
  #theme = shinytheme("superhero"),
  # Add the CSS 
  #tags$style(fmt_css),
  # Create a container for tab panels
  tabsetPanel(
    # Create "Table" tab
    tabPanel(
      title = "Iris",
      DT::dataTableOutput("table")
    )
  )
)
server <- function(input, output) {
  # Creating a reactive variable named "filtered_data"
  filtered_data <- reactive({
    # Filter the data (copied from previous exercise)
    data <- iris
    
    data
  })
  
  
  output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({
    data <- filtered_data()
    
    
    DT::datatable(data,
                  rownames = FALSE,
                  #filter="top",
                  # editable = TRUE,
                  class = 'cell-border',
                  escape = FALSE,
                  #container = table_frame(),
                  options = table_options(),
                  extensions = 'Buttons'
    )
  })
  
  
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: You have a lot of extra code here, unrelated to coloring a cell and adjusting the highlighting behavior. If you could reduce it to a minimal reproducible example that shows just the specific issue to might help you solve it yourself and will help other folks when they try to help by making it clearer. No one in the world has `pv_ip_rescheduling` except for you, so no one can run the example without recreating data, which is painful

Comment: @Nate, I have edited the code and it should be reproducible now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is not hover as this would be a change in colour of the row when the mouse is just hovering over it (this is controlled by the `class` argument, the class `hover` is contained in the standard `display` class so it's default behaviour - which you've already changed).

I think what you are looking for is to not allow a row selection. This is controlled by the argument `selection`, you need to set it to `none`:

```
library(DT)
library(shiny)


table_options <- function() {
  list(
    dom = 'Bfrtip',
    #Bfrtip
    # pageLength = 10,
    buttons = list(
      c('copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'),
      list(
        extend = "collection",
        text = 'Show All',
        action = DT::JS(
          "function ( e, dt, node, config ) {
          dt.page.len(-1);
          dt.ajax.reload();}"
        )
      ),
      list(
        extend = "collection",
        text = 'Show Less',
        action = DT::JS(
          "function ( e, dt, node, config ) {
          dt.page.len(10);
          dt.ajax.reload();}"
        )
      )
    ),
    
    deferRender = TRUE,
    
    lengthMenu = list(c(-1,10,20), c('All', '10', '20')),
    searching = TRUE,
    #editable = TRUE,
    scroller = TRUE,
    lengthChange = FALSE
    ,
    initComplete = JS(
      "function(settings, json) {",
      "$(this.api().table().header()).css({'background-color': '#517fb9', 'color': '#fff'});",
      "}"
    )
  )
}


ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel( h1("Iris data view", align = 'center'),
              windowTitle = "Iris data "),
  #theme = shinytheme("superhero"),
  # Add the CSS 
  #tags$style(fmt_css),
  # Create a container for tab panels
  tabsetPanel(
    # Create "Table" tab
    tabPanel(
      title = "Iris",
      DT::dataTableOutput("table")
    )
  )
)
server <- function(input, output) {
  # Creating a reactive variable named "filtered_data"
  filtered_data <- reactive({
    # Filter the data (copied from previous exercise)
    data <- iris
    
    data
  })
  
  
  output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({
    data <- filtered_data()
    
    
    DT::datatable(data,
                  rownames = FALSE,
                  #filter="top",
                  # editable = TRUE,
                  class = 'cell-border',
                  escape = FALSE,
                  #container = table_frame(),
                  options = table_options(),
                  extensions = 'Buttons',
                  selection = "none"
    )
  })
  
  
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```